# Strange post score view when clicking on it

Tags: support, voting, user-interface

When I click on the score of a post, it gives me a different view:

> [image: screenshot]

What is this view showing me? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Congratulations! You recently reached the [*establish user* privilige](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) when your reputation crossed the 1,000 line:

[image: established user privilege at 1,000]

As part of the privilege you now have access the vote counts; clicking once on the score shows you how many up- and downvotes a post has received. The post in your screenshot has 2 downvotes, and 0 upvotes.

It lets you see exactly how the score on a question was formed:

[image: 14 score revealed as 17 up and 3 down]

You also earned yourself a user card; mouse-over your image and see it pop out:

> [image: user card pop out]

See the linked privilege page for all the details. You can see a full list of privileges, both earned and still in your future, at https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges.

You can find that link in your profile (right next to the *edit* link), or go to the help center.

Comment: You darn ninja ;-)

Comment: what other privileges is opening after 1k+ ?

Comment: @Anri: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges